# Return column headers as array (no blank rows) if column sum is not zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have a table with columns of components needed to create various products. This table is populated automatically as output data from another table.

For this example, we'll use this one:

| S Widgets | M Widgets | L Widgets | XL Widgets | XXL Widgets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| 0 | 6 | 0 | 4 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 9 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

Ideally, the the output would look like this:

| Component | Total |
| --- | --- |
| M Widgets | 13 |
| XL Widgets | 11 |
| XXL Widgets | 29 |

What's the best way to get a list of headers for columns >0 without gaps? I know how I can get the total column done after I get the component column done, but I'm drawing a blank on the formula component column.

Help?

Comment: For a non-formula solution, you could easily create your output table (with just values, no formulas) using Power Query.  Unpivot your data to =>2  columns.  Then filter out the zero columns and Group by the Attribute aggregating by Sum.  I'm not familiar with Zoho but if just a data table would work, I could post something.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use the integrated filters, as I need to be able to use that elsewhere in the same sheet. Zoho is VERY frustrating as far as calculation times, function support, etc, but as it's what our company is using, it's what I'm working in. Supported spreadsheet Functions can be found here: https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/functions

Comment: If there's a workaround or AGGREGATE equivalent, I don't mind longer/circuitous formulas. Unfortunately that function isn't supported. Otherwise, the formula proposed below is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

with Office 365 we can leverage MMULT and FILTER to return the desired:

```
=LET(
    ttl,    A1:E1,
    val,    A2:E6,
    mmlt,   MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(val)^0),val),
    CHOOSE({1,2},TRANSPOSE(FILTER(ttl,mmlt>0)),TRANSPOSE(FILTER(mmlt,mmlt>0))))
```

Basically the `MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(val)^0),val)` returns a horizontal array of the sums of each column.

Then it is a matter of using filter first on the Titles to filter only those that have a sum greater than 0.

Then we filter the vertical array of the sums on the same filter.

We use CHOOSE to return the two side by side.

This uses the dynamic arrays and will spill the results from one formula.

[image]

---

Without Office 365 we need to use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$1,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(A1:E1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:E1))+1)/(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$2:$E$6)^0),$A$2:$E$6)>0),ROW($A1))),"")
```

And copy down to get the list.

We still use MMULT to return a horizontal array of the sums of the columns, but we use AGGREGATE to return the relative column number of each column that has a sum greater than 0.

As we copy it down it returns the first, then the second then the third.

[image]

Then we use SUM with INDEX to return the correct column:

```
=IF(M2<>"",SUM(INDEX($A$2:$E$6,0,MATCH(M2,$A$1:$E$1,0))),"")
```

The INDEX/MATCH returns the full column where the column title matches the value from the first formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, Scott! In my current data set, Row 3 are headers, and they start on E. When I do a three column test, I get an error. I converted the 2nd formula as follows: 
IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$G$3,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(E3:G3)-MIN(COLUMN(E3:G3))+1)/(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW($E$4:$G$17)^0),$E$4:$G$17)>0),ROW($E3)))
Getting a #NUM error if I remove IFERROR. Any ideas?

Comment: `ROW($E3)` should be `ROW($A1)`  It is just a counter.  The first should always be `$A1`

Comment: OH! Thank you! That, and filling in empty cells with 0 got the first column header to appear. Copying down though seems to break it, though...

Comment: Found the error in my conversion! Thank you!

Comment: Everything looks great in Excel. God help me- I'm importing into Zoho, and apparently it doesn't like the aggregate function. If you have any other ideas, I'm all ears. Otherwise, I truly appreciate that you were able to provide a solution for outside of Zoho!